# Spring MVC checkbox with Materializecss

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, materialize

I am using Spring MVC checkbox with materialize css and it is not showing up at all.

Here is what i am doing. i am using simple checkbox in jsp like this (without materializecss).

```
<form:checkbox path="nameID" value="store"  id="nameid_3" />
```

Checkbox gets displayed correctly.Now when i embedded materializecss, checkbox does not appear on the screen.

So i went further to check what is really going on behind the wall and  found this.

```
<input id="nameid_3" name="nameID" type="checkbox" value="store" checked="checked"><input type="hidden" name="_nameID" value="on">
```

Checkbox with hidden field and that's the problem.

When i deleted this hidden field in inspect element in chrome it worked.

So now questions how do i stop generating this hidden field with Spring MVC tag..? or is there alternate approach..?

and i am bound to use Spring MVC tag for validitions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found an alternate approach to remove these hidden fields. As we can see, there is a linking between name of checkbox and its hidden element. As we can see these field names are differentiated only using underscore. So we can remove these hidden fields using jQuery like this.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {

        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        $('[name="' + '_' + name + '"]').remove();

});
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer now materialized checkboxes  appeared  correctly and working fine,but will it not affect any functionality..?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Yes it will not affect your functionality because these hidden fields not connected in anyway  with  checkboxes.

Comment: This solution does not allow you to unselect a checkbox that was previously selected.  This is problematic in a multi-step form, where the user can move forward/backward.